# Invariant Violation when using external component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm working on making a change to a react component that is written in typescript. The change that I am making to the codebase involves removing a component that we own in favor for an external library [react-dual-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dual-listbox).

As soon as I import the dependency, all of my existing tests have started to fail and I'm not quite sure of why. The error I'm receiving is

```
Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string 
(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: 
undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `default_1`.
```

Here is my test file:

```
import { shallow, configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';
import PolicyEditor, { PolicyEditorProps } from '../PolicyEditor';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const defaultProps: PolicyEditorProps = {
  id: 'id',
  serviceId: 'service id',
  data: { data: { policy: { id: '1', name: 'policy', permissions: [] } } },
  permissionsData: { data: { service: { id: '1', permissions: [] } } },
  create: jest.fn(),
  update: jest.fn(),
  updatePermissions: jest.fn(),
  delete: jest.fn(),
  back: jest.fn(),
};

describe('PolicyEditor.tsx', () => {
  it('sets the state when the name is changed', done => {
    const wrapper = mount(<PolicyEditor {...defaultProps} />);
    const input = wrapper.find('input[id="policyName"]').first();

    const event = { target: { value: 'new policy name' } };

    input.simulate('change', event);

    process.nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.state().name).toEqual('new policy name');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Component:

```
import 'react-dual-listbox/lib/react-dual-listbox.css';

import * as React from 'react';
import { MutationFn } from 'react-apollo';
import { isQueryReady, isQueryLoading } from '../util/actionHelpers';
import {
  Permission,
  PolicyWithPermissions,
  ServicePermissionsQueryResult,
  PolicyQueryResult,
} from './types';
import AuthModal from '../shared/AuthModal';
import { Container, Row, Col, Label, Button, Form, FormGroup, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import DualListBox from 'react-dual-listbox';

export interface PolicyEditorProps {
  id?: string;
  serviceId: string;
  data: PolicyQueryResult;
  permissionsData: ServicePermissionsQueryResult;
  create: MutationFn;
  update: MutationFn;
  updatePermissions: MutationFn;
  delete: MutationFn;
  back(): void;
}

interface PolicyEditorState {
  name: string;
  selectedPermissions: Permission[];
}

export default class extends React.Component<PolicyEditorProps, PolicyEditorState> {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(
    nextProps: PolicyEditorProps,
    prevState: PolicyEditorState
  ): Partial<PolicyEditorState> | null {
    if (nextProps.id && isQueryReady(nextProps.data)) {
      const policy: PolicyWithPermissions = nextProps.data.data!.policy;

      return {
        name: policy.name,
        selectedPermissions: policy.permissions,
      };
    }

    if (!nextProps.id) {
      return {
        name: '',
      };
    }

    return null;
  }

  constructor(props: PolicyEditorProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      selectedPermissions: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    const isEdit: boolean = !!this.props.id;
    if (isEdit) {
      if (isQueryLoading(this.props.data)) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
      if (this.props.data.error !== undefined) {
        return <div>Something went wrong!</div>;
      }
    }

    const { loading, error } = this.props.permissionsData;
    return (
      <AuthModal title="Policy Editor" isOpen={true} toggle={this.props.back}>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="policyName">Name</Label>
            <Input
              id="policyName"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
              value={this.state.name}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          {isEdit ? (
            <div>
              <hr />
              {loading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
              ) : error ? (
                <div>Error</div>
              ) : (
                <Container className="m-2">
                  <Row>
                    <Col className="text-center" xs="6">
                      Available Permissions
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="text-center" xs="6">
                      Current Permissions
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <DualListBox
                    canFilter={true}
                    options={this.props.permissionsData.data!.service.permissions.map(p => ({
                      value: p.id,
                      label: p.name,
                    }))}
                    selected={this.state.selectedPermissions.map(p => p.id)}
                    onChange={this.updateSelectedPermissions}
                  />
                </Container>
              )}
              <FormGroup>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs={{ size: 1 }}>
                    <Button onClick={this.onUpdate} color="success">
                      Update
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs={{ size: 1, offset: 1 }}>
                    <Button onClick={this.onDelete} color="danger">
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </FormGroup>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <FormGroup>
              <Button color="success" onClick={this.onCreate}>
                Create
              </Button>
            </FormGroup>
          )}
        </Form>
      </AuthModal>
    );
  }
}
```

The error message seems cryptic. It appears to tell me that it expected *something* to be a string, but was undefined. I'm not quite sure what exactly is undefined. However, I am able to get the tests passing if I simply don't render the `DualListBox`, but that doesn't help my problem.

The odd thing is that it works as expected in the browser with no errors, and the problem is only with my tests. Apparently people who have this same error message it ends up being an import issue, but If it works in the browser, it must be importing correctly, no?

Is there something that I'm missing or not understanding here?